# Android app not installed when network is available

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android developing. I created a simple app that loads a url by WebView. It works fine on emulator and most devices. But in some cases, specially whit devices that run android lower than 6, when network is available I get the error "app not installed". But after disabling wifi and data, app installs without a problem

I tried everything I found on the web. Including:
Change signature version.
Uninstall app completely from target device.
Uninstall old jdk an install the last version.

This is how i defined internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And this how i defined signing config

```
 signingConfigs {
      release {
        storeFile file("myKey.jks")
        storePassword '*******'
        keyAlias 'alias'
        keyPassword '****'
        v2SigningEnabled false

    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

And this is how i loaded the webview:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView myWebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewOne);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
}

   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       if (myWebView.canGoBack()){
        myWebView.goBack();
       }else {super.onBackPressed();}

   }

}
```

I chose minSdkVersion 19 and targetSdkVersion 29. I expected that the app runs on android 4.4 and above without a problem. But in some devices that run android 5.1 i get the error "app not installed" when the wify and data is available

Comment: How did you load the url?

Comment: I edited the question and added the loading url codde

Comment: Perhaps related, is there a reason you have `v2SigningEnabled` on disabled?

Comment: i found in searching that v2Signing is not compatible whit old versions of android, so I added v2SigningEnabled false. but before doing this, iget the same error